# how to get non integer column in another table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I have 2 columns `coupons` and `carts` in my carts table migrations I have `coupon_code` which will get code from `coupons` table and the result will be cutoff price from total price in cart.

This is my cart migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('coupon_code')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('carts', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->foreign('coupon_code')->references('code')->on('coupons');
        });
    }
```

and I get this error when I try to run `php artisan migrate`

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `carts` add constraint `carts_coupon_code_foreign` foreign key (`coupon_co
  de`) references `coupons` (`code`))

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

How can I solve that?

## Update

`Coupon` migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('coupons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->decimal('amount');
            $table->date('valid_from');
            $table->date('valid_to');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> Idea!

**What if I make `coupon_code` string and nullable in my carts table and then make it scope to validate coupon code from coupons table then cutoff the price? do you think that will work? and if yes, is there someone to help me with that scope?**

Comment: can you show us your coupons table migration. Does all of your carts will have coupon_code? if not you might need to  make coupon_code to nullable in carts table.

Comment: Make sure that coupon_code in carts table has the same type as code field  in coupons table

Comment: @usrNotFound Updated my question, and no coupon code will be add to cart and it effect total price of cart is not about single product.

Comment: @YouneL can you be more specific please?

Comment: @mafortis every carts will have coupons is that right?

Comment: @usrNotFound yes there will be input box bottom of cart page to insert coupon codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that both fields have different datatype, for example in your carts table coupon_code field is an unsigned integer but on coupons table you have code field as strings.

carts migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('coupon_code')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('carts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign('coupon_code')->references('code')->on('coupons');
    });
}
```

**Validate coupon_code (IN carts controller for example):**

```
public function add_to_cart(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'coupon_code' => 'nullable|exist:coupons,code',
    ]);

    if ($request->has('coupon_code')) {

         // get code here
         $code = $request->input('coupon_code');

    }
}
```

Comment: it return error `General error: 1215` . I also have an idea included my question please consider that as well, thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can add nullable method to your coupon code like above

Comment: OK, now is saving tables, but as `coupon_code` is string how I check which user will input is actual coupon code or just typing something? I mean need some sort of validation to coupons table, how do i do that?

Comment: You can use laravel [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) to check if a user input match a coupon_code, use the [exist](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists) rule